# Problema ao carregar cor detectada pelo arduino

Tags: python, opencv, processamento-de-imagens

Estou com um problema ao carregar as informações no Arduino via pyserial.

Eu estou usando um script python e opencv para fazer a detecção de cores via webcam. Para cada cor detectada, quero informar o Arduino para que ele possa tomar uma decisão. Mas não consigo enviar os dados para o Arduino.

Este é o programa que estou usando em python

```
#importando módulos

import cv2   
import numpy as np
import serial
import time
import os    

#COM 4 = porta serial que está ligada o arduino
#115200 = baudrate
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200, timeout = .5)

#capturando vídeo através da webcam

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while(1):
    _, imagem = cap.read()
    #quadro de conversão (imagem, ou seja, BGR) para HSV (valor de saturação de matiz)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(imagem, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    #define a gama de cor vermelha
    red_lower = np.array([136, 87, 111], np.uint8)
    red_upper = np.array([180, 255, 255], np.uint8)

    #define a gama de cor azul
    blue_lower = np.array([99, 115, 150], np.uint8)
    blue_upper = np.array([110, 255, 255], np.uint8)

    #define a gama de cor verde
    green_lower = np.array([22, 60, 200], np.uint8)
    green_upper = np.array([60, 255, 255], np.uint8)

    #encontrar o intervalo de cor vermelha, azul e amarela na imagem
    red = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)
    blue = cv2.inRange(hsv, blue_lower, blue_upper)
    green = cv2.inRange(hsv, green_lower, green_upper)

    #Transformação Morfológica, Dilatação   
    kernal = np.ones((5 ,5), "uint8")
    red = cv2.dilate(red, kernal)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(imagem, imagem, mask = red)
    blue = cv2.dilate(blue, kernal)
    res1 = cv2.bitwise_and(imagem, imagem, mask = blue)
    green = cv2.dilate(green, kernal)
    res2 = cv2.bitwise_and(imagem, imagem, mask = green)

    #Seguindo a cor vermelha
    (_, contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(red, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if (area > 300):
            x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour) 
            imagem = cv2.rectangle(imagem,(x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(imagem, "Vermelho",(x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255))
        if (ser.inWaiting() > 0):
            ser.write(b"2")

    #Seguindo a cor azul
    (_, contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(blue, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if (area > 300):
           x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour) 
           imagem = cv2.rectangle(imagem, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
           cv2.putText(imagem, "Azul", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (255, 0, 0))
       if (ser.inWaiting() > 0):
          ser.write(b'1')
   #Seguindo a cor verde
   (_, contours, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(green, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
   for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
       area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
       if (area > 300):
           x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour) 
           imagem = cv2.rectangle(imagem, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
           cv2.putText(imagem, "Verde", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (0, 255, 0))
       if (ser.inWaiting() > 0):
           ser.write(b'3')

    cv2.imshow("Seguindo a Cor", imagem)

    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        ser.close()
        cap.release()            
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

E esse é o script do Arduino:

```
char incoming;
const int led1 = 2;
const int led2 = 4;
const int led3 = 6;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char incoming = Serial.read();
    if (incoming == '1') {
      digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Led 1 on");
    }
    else if (incoming == '2') {
      digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Led 2 on");
    }
    else if (incoming == '3') {
      digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
      Serial.println("Led 3 on");
    }
    else {}
  }
}
```

No entanto, ao executar o programa em python, o arduino só reinicia e não recebe dados via serial. Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse problema?

Comment: Mas o programa é executado normalmente? Já tentou jogar a saída direto para o terminal para saber se o Python ao menos está gerando os valores esperados?

Comment: sim o programa em python funciona normalmente, identifica e rastreia as cores especificadas, não tentei, na verdade não conheço esse comando, vou pesquisar sobre e tentar aplicar... Obrigado

Comment: Ao invés de `ser.write`, use `print` e acompanhe pelo terminal os valores

Comment: realmente nao funciona, ele não escreve no terminal... voce saberia o motivo?

Comment: Não, então tudo indica que o problema não é com a comunicação entre o Python e o Arduino, mas só no programa Python. Provavelmente alguma lógica/condição errada. Tente executar o programa com o debug ligado para ver exatamente o que está acontecendo.

Comment: amigo, realmente o problema estava no programa em python, tive de retirar o função  if (ser.inWaiting() > 0): porque ela estava esperando um sinal do arduino para liberar a conexão. agora funciona normalemente... com o debug ligado eu conseguiria identificar essa falha? se sim, como habilito ele?

Comment: Leia sobre a biblioteca [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html)